# Baileys chocolate mousse - an alternative liqueur

Tags: pairing, liqueur

Chocolate mousse made with Baileys is pretty much heaven.  However, what other liqueurs (not generic Baileys) would give this favorite dessert a well needed kick?  Here is the link to make the [Bailey's mousse](http://www.baileys.com/en-row/recipes/desserts/baileys-chocolate-mousse.html).  I want to be able to taste the liqueur as if I were drinking it, but without it overpowering the chocolate (or falling over sideways).

Comment: Would it work with a caramel vodka, such as Smirnoff Kissed Caramel, or better, salted caramel vodka (such as Effen, Pinnacle, or Stoli)? The Bailey's has a bit of cream, so you might have to adjust (or use its recipe for fudge and 'pair' with vodka shots).

Comment: I like the salted caramel vodka, dash there goes the diet!

Comment: @Nat Bowman.  Many thanks for your edits, boy what a dumbo I was not to spot those!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a massive fan of Bailey's myself, but do love a chocolate mousse. Since unless you're going way overboard with the alcohol, you're not really going to disrupt the mousse and make it soupy, you can use anything that **you** think goes with chocolate. Personally, I love the following paired with a good **dark** chocolate:

- Kahlua/Tia Maria (most similar in spirit to Bailey's)
- Port or madeira
- Deep but not too peaty Scotch
- Dark rum (I'd leave the [continental "rums"](http://www.stroh.at/en/products/stroh-original/) to fruit desserts, where they excel)
- Brandy
- Kirsch

I'd avoid lighter or delicate / floral spirits, since they don't really work (for me) with a deep dark chocolate.

I'd keep it to under about a shot per cup to avoid thinning the mousse too much. And please try a *tiny* pinch of salt, which the original recipe is missing but is essential for a good chocolate dessert!

Comment: Yup you are right about the salt - thanks for your advice and the answer.